# Access a value from the current theme in an xml layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

I want a specific TextView to have the same font size as a Button, but they appear to be different.  If my Button is not setting a custom textSize, how can I grab this value from the current theme and set it to the textSize of my TextView?

Answer (score 0):

It should be fairly simple with styles. Buttons parent is android.widget.TextView so you could make a style that uses this as parent and overwrite the default textSize. Then let both use this style.